# How to disable Pretty URL in Laragon

Tags: apache, webserver, virtualhost, vhosts, laragon

How can i completely disable pretty URL feature of **Laragon**, so for example right now by default in Laragon pretty URL is set as `{name}.test` where `{name}` is root folder and `test` is any string of our choice.
so in **Laragon** i access my wordpress admin (*root folder demo* ) as:
[http://demo.test/wp-admin/](https://#)
but i want to access it as:
[http://localhost/demo/wp-admin/](https://#)

Answer (score -2):

You can always access the page or web app with http://localhost URL.

If you don't want to use the "pretty url" (a.k.a. virtual host feature), you can turn it of in installer or in Laragon settings.

Images from https://laragon.org/docs/install.html :
[image]
[image]

**Laragon doesn't remove existing virtual host configuration when you turn off "Auto virtual hosts" in configuration.**

To remove the virtual host, you have to remove it from the etc/hosts file of your OS. You can use "Edit etc/hosts" from the Laragon's Menu. Remove the lines with `#laragon magic!` comment. Deleting a project using the Laragon's Menu removes the line from hosts too.

[image]

To fully cleanup the virtual server configuration, remove `server_name` from [auto.{project}.test.conf](https://laragon.org/docs/pretty-urls.html)

Answer (score -2):

What you describe is called `base_url` in wordpress it's called `siteurl` in the config.

Than just create an apache config like

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    servername localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www>
        AllowOverride All
        require all granted
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Mind ellaborating on your answer? how? where?